# Python Selenium is not able to hit the button

Tags: python, selenium

Can someone help me and take a look what I am missing that my selenium script is not able to hit the button "Einloggen bei my onvista"?

```
def open_browser():
    chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chromeOptions.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe',options=chromeOptions)
    return (driver)

def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True


driver = open_browser()

url = 'https://my.onvista.de/login'
driver.get(url)


check_exists_by_xpath("//*[text()='Einloggen bei my onvista']")

el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Einloggen bei my onvista']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", el)
```

It works fine when setting the element to another button:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Zum onvista bank Webtrading ']")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xpath `//*[text()='Einloggen bei my onvista']` which you are using returns list of element h1 header and your button that's the reason you are facing issue while clicking on your button. Please refer below solutin to resolve your issue.

Also ,try to induce WebDriverWait while clicking on button this could be synchronization issue,

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Einloggen bei my onvista')]"))).click()
```

or

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
element=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Einloggen bei my onvista')]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```